# ansible include_var not working

Tags: ansible

I want to import variables from a playbook A into a playbook B :

Playbook B :

```
 
---
- hosts: portal
  sudo: no

  tasks:

  - include_vars: varz.yml

  - debug: var=vars

  - debug: var=x
```

playbook A :

```
  vars:

    x: 123
    y: abc
```

The result I get is :

```
TASK: [debug var=x] *********************************************************** 
ok: [192.168.78.10] => {
    "x": "{{ x }}"
}
```

I was expecting X: 123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change playbook A to the following, `vars:` is not needed

```
---
  x: 123
  y: abc
```